# Calculate the probability of sampling the same number of real and fake gold coins

Tags: probability

Julien is invited to open one of two treasure chests. He is twice as likely to open treasure chest $A$ than treasure chest $B$.

In treasure chest $A$, there are $15$ gold coins. However, $60\%$ of them are fake. In treasure chest $B$, there are $8$ gold coins. However, $25\%$ of them are fake. After selecting a treasure chest to open, Julien randomly samples four coins.

Calculate the probability that Julien samples an equal number of real and fake gold coins from the random sample of four.

I tried to do a binomial for each

$P(\text{ choosing real gold coins from A)}={15\choose 2}(.4)^2(.6)^{13}$
$P(\text{ choosing real gold coins from B)}={8\choose 2}(.75)^2(.25)^6$

And the fakes are just the probabilities switched so like $(.4)^{13}(.6)^2$ for A, now the probability of choosing $A$ is $2\over 3$ and $B$ is $1\over 3$ so here is where I get stuck. I'm not sure if I should do $$P(A)P(2 \text{ real from A) $P($$2$ fake from A})+P(B)P(2 \text{ real from B) $P($$2$ fake from B})$$
or not.

Comment: I included the scenario using the binomial. Compare it with your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in chest A there are 6 reals and 9 fakes, and in chest B there are 6 reals and 2 fakes.

Let $R$ be the number of reals sampled, and $F$ be the number of fakes sampled.

Presumably, you sample *without* replacement since it (it doesn't make sense to put the coins back in the chest). So the probabilities are not constant among the draws and therefore you cannot model $R$ and $F$ as binomial random variables. Instead, you model them as hypergeometric random variables.

So let $A$ be the event that he chooses chest A and let $B$ be the event that he chooses chest B. Notice that if we draw $R = 2$, then $F = 2$ since we draw $n = 4$ coins and there are only two kinds of coins. Then

\begin{align*}
P(R = 2) &= P(A, R = 2) +P(B, R = 2)\\
&=P(R = 2|A)P(A)+P(R=2|B)P(B)\\
&=\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{15}{4}}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{8}{4}}\cdot \frac{1}{3}\\
&=\frac{61}{182}\\
&\approx 0.335.
\end{align*}

---

If for some strange reason you sample *with* replacement, then yes you can model $R$ and $F$ as binomial random variables. However, notice again that in four draws, if $R=2$, then automatically $F = 2$ since there are only two kinds of coins. So you only have to find the chance that $R=2$ in each case. Then
\begin{align*}
P(R = 2) &= P(A, R = 2) +P(B, R = 2)\\
&=P(R = 2|A)P(A)+P(R=2|B)P(B)\\
&=\binom{4}{2}(.40)^2(1-.40)^{4-2}\cdot \frac{2}{3}+\binom{4}{2}(.75)^2(1-.75)^{4-2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}\\
&\approx 0.301.
\end{align*}